# Offsetting symbology position in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, symbology

My data of polylines has lots of attributes to be rendered with a symbology, I made it such that each attribute of interest would be a layer. I would like to display each of these layers at the same time so that the attributes could be seen at the same time. Since the top layers cover the lower ones, I set the symbology so that the layers would have increasing different thickness, with the most bottom layer having the thickest line.

Is there a better way to do this, like offsetting a layer's symbology a little bit to the left or right so that each layer can be displayed side by side? Visually, something like [this](http://img685.imageshack.us/img685/6178/linediagram.png).

I'm using ArcGIS 10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ArcGIS has the ability to offset lines in the symbology settings.  Make sure your lines are set to **Cartographic Line Symbol** and you will be able to offset the line on the **Line Properties** tab.

In the attached image, I have created a line style with three lines.  The blue is offset -5, the red is offset +5, the green has an offset of 0.[image]

You could offset each of your layers differently.  You might have to play around with them to get it just the way you want it.

There's more about creating line styles on [ESRI's website](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Creating_line_symbols/00s60000000p000000/).