# Displaying parallel line information

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, fields-attributes, parallel-lines

I would like to display information of a line feature in parallel. For example, a river line feature with its different qualities. I want to avoid a parallel copy of line features. Is it possible to achieve this with display symbology options in ArcMap?
For clearance:
[image: http://wbv-untere-warnow-kueste.de/fileadmin/_processed_/csm_6_5_GWzustand_karte_76134b7b82.jpg]

from: [http://wbv-untere-warnow-kueste.de/fileadmin/*processed*/csm_6_5_GWzustand_karte_76134b7b82.jpg](http://wbv-untere-warnow-kueste.de/fileadmin/_processed_/csm_6_5_GWzustand_karte_76134b7b82.jpg)

Comment: When you mention that you want to avoid "a parallel copy of line features" do you mean a physical copy of the shapefile, or multiple copies of the same shapefile in the Table of Contents (ToC) in ArcMap?

Comment: Is this what you want? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28808/offsetting-symbology-position-in-arcgis-desktop

Comment: @BERA It looks like that to me

Comment: @Keagan Allan: I mean to avoid a physical copy of a line feature inside a shapefile. A copy of a shapefile in the ToC is no problem.